# Couldn't find modelDataContext

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq, namespaces

Im trying to use LINQ in my ASP.NET/C# website. For that I need to access the class 'modelDataContext' which is a part of the LINQ namespace.

Im using **Visual Studio 2010 Professional**

**This is my C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class admin_new_feed : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        modelDataContext data = new modelDataContext();
    }
}
```

**Full error message I get**

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'modelDataContext' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

**Things i've tried, which doesn't solve problem**

- Adding the reference (Right-click solution, add reference - System.Data.Linq)
- Re-create the website
- Right clicking on the line, to see if the tab "Resolve" was there. But it wasn't.

Comment: Is DataContext only? Without model ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx

Comment: I know theres a DataContext also. But now i wanted to work with 'modelDataContext', which is my question.

Comment: Same Error. Couldn't find it.

Comment: You need EntityFramework.dll

Comment: I got that. Isn't the problem. The problem is that it can't find the namespace for modelDataContext, which has something to do with a Namespace/reference somewhere..

Comment: Did you created .edmx file?